# How do you multiply a number by a key value from a nested object?

Tags: python, dictionary

Im getting an error in this code:

```
def SellFor(Price,Vehicle):
    WheelsCost=(Vehicles[Vehicle][Wheels]*200)
    TotalPrice=WheelsCost
    if Price > (TotalPrice+1000):
        return False
    else:
        return True
while True:
    try:
        Price=int(input("Input Price to sell: "))
    except:
        print("\n Invalid Input. \n")
    else:break
    if SellFor(Price,VehicleToSell):
        Money+=Price
        del Vehicles[VehicleToSell]
        print()
        print("Vehicle Sold. \n")
        break
    else:
        print("Price too large.")
```

I am making a vehicle construction game and this is only part of the script for when you sell the vehicle.

When assigning the `WheelsCost` variable you can notice that I gave it a value of another variable with two indexes and that variable is a dictionary and with the indexes I am accessing an object / dictionary from within the primary dictionary then in that secondary object im accessing a key value.

I am getting an error when the function is run in this line of code `WheelsCost=(Vehicles[Vehicle][Wheels]*200)` in the function and the error says: `KeyError: 4` , when making the vehicle i give it 4 wheels (so it would be car) and so I presume thats where the `4` in the `KeyError` comes from.

and so my goal in this is to multiply the number of wheels, in this scenario lets say 4, by 200 and so I did it in the way shown in the code since thats how you retrieve a value from an object but that seems to raise an error and so i edited that line of code and directly converted it to an integer because I thought that the computer was getting confused by the key and the value so I changed it to this: `WheelsCost=(int(Vehicles[Vehicle][Wheels])*200)` but that still raised the same error so at this point i'm stuck, I cant think of anything else to do and please don't be so harsh I know its a simple objective just multiplying two numbers but i genuinely don't know what to do.

`Wheels` is not a local variable so i cant just access it, i have to reference the entire dictionary, also instead of `print(Vehicles[Vehicle])` i use a for loop to print it out neatly:

```
   Type : ground
   Colour : red
   Wheels : 4
   TopSpeed : 120
   Acceleration : 70
   Seats : 5
   Engines : 1
   Electric : False
   PlateNumber : 123456
```

all the given values are given by the user and are not hardcoded.

Comment: It should just be `Wheels * 200` if `Wheels` is the number of wheels in a vehicle.

Comment: Can you show `print(Vehicles[Vehicle])`? It's not obvious how you've structured your data.

Comment: If `Vehicles` is a list of dictionaries, the key should be a string. `Vehicles[Vehicles]['wheels']`

Comment: @Barmar Ok ill try that hopefully it works

Comment: @Barmar yess you're right it worked thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wheels` is a dictionary key, which is a string. You need to quote it.

```
WheelsCost Vehicles[Vehicle]['Wheels'] * 200
```

Without the quotes it's treated as a variable, and the value of the global variable is apparently `4`. So it's trying to find a dictionary key `4`, which doesn't exist.